# Python run time on Windows vs Linux

Tags: python, linux, windows

So I created a Python data mining program that takes some useful information from about 4000 lines of data. Anyways, I run it on windows 10 and it takes about 1 minute to complete. I tried running it on Linux (latest Ubuntu) and I let it sit for 30 minutes without completion. Then I loaded back into windows and it completes in less than a minute. Both version have latest Python version.

In general I actually thought it would be faster on my Linux OS (same computer). But the comparison is not even close. I didn't even let it finish on Linux because it took so long.

Any explanations? I have a feeling there's more info you might need so I'm happy to try to provide it, I tried to provide anything relevant I could think of initially here.

Comment: Strange. Could you open your system monitor and see if in one case it's using several cores and in the other just one? Also, is your program using the GPU?

Comment: So many things it could be.  Is the data identical?  What else is running on the machine?  You say "same machine", how are the disks partitioned?   How are you running two operating systems on the same machine, is one a VM?  You really need to look at system wide statistics to begin to guess.  Where I would start is to look at I/O, it sounds like the Linux version is doing some sort of network access, but I can't imagine why that would be.

Comment: It sounds like its getting stuck in a loop for some reason on Windows.  I would start by sprinkling some prints around your code.  Then try running with the smallest data set that you can.

Comment: Just had a thought, you are using the same machine for both operating systems, are you sharing a data partition using something like Samba?

Comment: @Mateo I tried running with a smaller data set, and the program ran quick and correctly. Plus it works on windows with both small and large data set, so I can't imagine something is wrong with my code for it to enter an "infinite loop" or something.

Comment: @cdarke Yeah, it's the same machine for both operating systems. Each operating system is on it's own separate SSD.